# Java Hibernate and XML not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this project in which I have to use hibernate, this is the first time I use, I don't really know many things about it and I get a bunch of exceptions when I run my program. I have installed the required libraries from hibernate in eclipse. But when I run I get this. I'm sorry that I paste all the errors here but I really have no idea how I could fix them and where to start. Could you please help me

```
    Mar 31, 2014 9:44:05 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:05 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.8.Final}
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Book.hbm.xml
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:06 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:06 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:06 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:06 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/Lab1-aop]
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:06 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at library.repository.file.RepositoryFile.<init>(RepositoryFile.java:17)
    at controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:18)
    at view.Library.<init>(Library.java:23)
    at Start.createAndShowGUI(Start.java:14)
    at Start$1.run(Start.java:28)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:08 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mar 31, 2014 9:44:08 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: model.Book
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at library.repository.file.RepositoryFile.<init>(RepositoryFile.java:17)
    at controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:18)
    at view.Library.<init>(Library.java:23)
    at Start.createAndShowGUI(Start.java:14)
    at Start$1.run(Start.java:28)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.Book
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:126)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: You need to add the `mysql` jar too to your classpath. Hibernate is just the median, the actual DB is `mysql` and its jar is required by hibernate internally.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing mysql-connector jar in your classpath and hence the exception.

Comment: Now I downloaded the mysql-connector and unziped it. But know I have to copy all the jar files in my lib folder from my project and then add all of them to the path?

Comment: @user3421241 How is your project organized? Do you use Maven or some other tool to manage dependencies? Do you use an IDE?

Comment: Just add mysql jar to classpath. If you are using eclipse for running this and all your jars in lib folder. Then copy this mysql-connector jar to lib folder and this to your project build path.

Comment: I have added the mysql-connector but now I get another errors :( I have pasted them above

Comment: @user3421241 Good so u have moved one step ahead now. Now your code is trying to make a connection but failing. So make sure you are using the right connection string and your database is up and listening.

Comment: I don't know how to do that ..Can you please help me

Comment: @user3421241 i believe you are running too fast on the learning path without actually grabbing the stuff. So slow down, read and try to learn what you are trying to achieve with the code u have in hand. I may not be able to help u, its now u who has to help himself. Good Luck!

Comment: I have the database done, I mean I have a table in it and some records. How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 0):

```
Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found
```

Include it in you classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **mysql-connector jar** .. Kindly download appropriate version and put it in your project class path.. this will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Your Exception shows below lines

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found

That means your jdbc driver is not added in library or properly configured.

Please check your config file

You're missing the Mysql Connection JAR on your classpath.

This jar contains the driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Download it and add,problem  will be solved

```
you can download mysql java driver from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
```